# Appharbor JustOneDB https request from C# getting 400 errors

Tags: c#, https, httpwebrequest, appharbor, justonedb

I am trying to do a https GET to JustOneDB it works if I do it from the curl utility.  But its NOT working from C#.
I get  (400) Bad Request

I searched around and disabled security and all that but its still not working.  Any ideas?
Has anyone done this w/ rest and JustOneDB?

This works along w/ all the other rest examples:

`curl -k -XGET 'https://username:password@77.92.68.105:31415/justonedb/database/database name'`

This DON'T work: I Dummied the string to remove my passcode.

```
   public ActionResult JustOneDb()
    {
        ///////////
        HttpWebRequest request = null;
        HttpWebResponse response = null;
        try
        {

            String Xml;
            //curl -k -XGET 'https://zn0lvkpdhdxb70l2_DUMMY_urshn5e7i41lb3fiwuh@77.92.68.105:31415/justonedb/database/n10lvkpdhdxei0l2uja'
            string url = @"https://zn0lvkpdhdxb70_DUMMY_urshn5e7i41lb3fiwuh@77.92.68.105:31415/justonedb/database/n10lvkpdhdxei0l2uja";

            request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

            request.Method = "GET";

            request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

            // Ignore Certificate validation failures (aka untrusted certificate + certificate chains)
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true); 


            // Get response 
            using (response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                // Get the response stream 
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
                Xml = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            return Content(Xml);
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            return Content(ee.ToString());

        }
        //////////////

        ViewBag.fn = "*.xml";
        return View();
    }
```

Results:

```
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() 
at Mvc3Razor.Controllers.MyXmlController.JustOneDb() ...
```

TIA
FxM :{

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing the username password in the url, you should create the correct credentials with "username" and "password". You might also want to consider using something like [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) instead of the raw `WebRequest`.

Comment: RestSharp did not work either.  I think it has something to do w/ the certificate.    Other https sites work.  And curl works.  Really wanted to do Rest to JustOneDb cause the same App has a Perl peace.
Thanks.

Comment: Right, I'll get in touch with the JustOneDB guys.

Answer (score 0):

There was a mismatch with the certificate, which has been fixed. It is still self-signed, but now the hostname matches. We will be changing to use a fully signed certificate soon, but in the mean time please let me know if it works with just the self-signed override.

Comment: It still does not work.  The dot net is more restrictive then using just curl.  TA

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I copied the code, and the problem is that the HttpWebRequest library is not adding the authentication header in the original request. The solution is to insert the header manually, so if you add the following two lines after the 'request.Method = "GET" line (and remove the username/password from the URL string):

```
string authInfo = "zn0lvkpdhdxb70l2_DUMMY_urshn5e7i41lb3fiwuh";
request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(authInfo));
```

It should work correctly.